# Query posts only shows 1

Tags: wordpress

I have an array of ids:

```
var_dump($userPostsInternal);
  -> string(13) "128537,128545"
```

Then I do

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array($userPostsInternal),
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {
    $title = $post->title;
    echo $title;
}
```

But I only get 1 title. There are 2 articles and they do have the ids we see in the `var_dump();`

I even tried:

```
foreach ( $q->posts as $post ) {
    $title = get_the_title();
    echo $title;
```

But I still get one title only.

If I explode `$userPostsInternal` I get `array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "128537" [1]=> string(6) "128545" }` and no results at all

Comment: Not sure your call `array($userPostsInternal)` is doing exactly what you think it's doing - I'd expect you to be using [`explode()`](https://php.net/explode) to be creating a PHP array based on the delimited string. Simply passing a delimited string to `array()` does not (to my knowledge) explode the individual elements automatically.

Comment: @esqew ok I will try to explode it

Comment: @esqew If I explode I get array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "128537" [1]=> string(6) "128545" } and no results at all

Comment: You're also passing strings as parameters. If you've reviewed the documentation around [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), you'll notice that it's not explicitly mentioned, but each of their examples passes an int-casted item for each of the `post__in` array elements. You may be interested in attempting to typecast each to an integer to ensure that this type juggling is not creating issues for you.

Comment: @esqew thanks for your suggestion, I have provided my own answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this is the thing:

I used a query

```
$args = array(
    'post__in' => array($userPostsInternal),
```

Taking the fact the following is a string

```
var_dump($userPostsInternal);
  -> string(13) "128537,128545"
```

I thought declaring the array here would work

```
array($userPostsInternal)
```

But it's not, therefore thanks to a comment, suggesting me to explode `$userPostsInternal` converting the string into an array, I then had to remove the array declaration, making the query like:

```
$userPostsInternal = explode( ',' , $userPostsInternal);
$args = array(
    'post__in' => $userPostsInternal,
```

Answer (score 1):

After exploding, you must remove the array() from the query.

```
$string = '128537,128545';

$userPostsInternal = explode( ',' , $string);

$args = array(
    'post__in' => $userPostsInternal,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Yes.  I think we posted within a few seconds of each other. :)